# Why we need to change varchar to string in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm beginner to asp.net. I have doubt, I didn't know the exact explanation. But I used that concept in my code several place. For example `@session["userName"].ToString()`.

If anyone can tell exact answer, it will most helpful.

Comment: Where is the varchar you are talking about? @session["userName"] is of type object. AFAIK there is nothing named varchar in C#

Comment: @SirRufo userName is string data type in my model. but it will save in my database (sql) as varchar.

Comment: You never mentioned any database in your question. You should put all relevant informations in the question and remove all others. It will help to clearify your questions

Comment: @SirRufo I mentioned there asp.net and i thought one of asp.net expert could caught my point of view through my example.thus i didn't mention my database there.

Comment: Well, the whole question is not related to asp.net at all, because database access is not limited to asp.net. And your example also did not show any relation to varchar. It only make sense if you had mentioned database. Thats all

Comment: @SirRufo one of asp.net expert - Mohammad Olfatmiri answered  very well to my question without any clarification . that is called expert.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199478/discussion-between-niroshan-kumarasamy-and-sir-rufo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this [Link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4322/sql-server-differences-of-char-nchar-varchar-and-nvarchar-data-types/),it will provide the answer for your question. also, The column type nvarchar allows you to store Unicode characters, but varchar not like that.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings). please check the link for more information.

> SQL Server and the .NET Framework are based on different type systems.
>   For example, the .NET Framework Decimal structure has a maximum scale
>   of 28, whereas the SQL Server decimal and numeric data types have a
>   maximum scale of 38. To maintain data integrity when reading and
>   writing data, the SqlDataReader exposes SQL Server–specific typed
>   accessor methods that return objects of System.Data.SqlTypes as well
>   as accessor methods that return .NET Framework types. Both SQL Server
>   types and .NET Framework types are also represented by enumerations in
>   the DbType and SqlDbType classes, which you can use when specifying
>   SqlParameter data types.

Comment: Upvoted, but your answer would be better if the quote were about varchars and strings. (If such a quote exists in that doc.)